# Convert txt file encoding from DOS737 to UTF8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a txt file that has greek characters. When i open the file with notepad it shows that the encoding is ASCII.
But the only way that i can read the greek characters is to change (in openoffice writer or Editpad lite) the character set to DOS737.
The process that i need to implement in PHP is to open the file, split the text and import it to database. Everything is ok except that i cannot get the greek characters as they are.
I tried iconv but with no result.
I also tried mb_convert_encoding($data[0], "DOS737"); but i get warning  **mb_convert_encoding(): Unknown encoding "DOS737"**

Also tried utf8_encode but with no luck
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it.
It was easy... For anyone that might have the same issue use **iconv("cp737","UTF-8","$string");**

Comment: Many character encodings have multiple names. In the Internet context, IANA lists the [preferred ones](iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml#table-character-sets-1).